# Ionic HTTP not working in Function

Tags: ajax, angular, ionic3

I can't seem to get ajax to work inside my function, what am I doing wrong here?

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export class EmailValidator {

  static checkEmail ( control: FormControl ): any {
    var $http = new Http;

    return new Promise(resolve => {

      var lowercaseValue = control.value.toLowerCase();
      if(lowercaseValue.indexOf('@') <= -1 || lowercaseValue.indexOf('.') <= -1) {
        resolve({
            "invalid email": true
        });
      } else {
        $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '{URL}'+lowercaseValue
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          if(response.error == true) {
            resolve(response);
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          resolve({
              "invalid email": true
          });
        });
      }

    });

  }

}
```

The error I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`new Http()` call requires 2 parameters:

```
constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions)
```

https://angular.io/api/http/Http

Try adding it as an argument to the constructor method for your class:

```
export class EmailValidator {
  contstructor($http: Http) {}
  ...
```

You also need to import the `HttpModule` into your bootstrap code, something like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Still no go with a constructor class: http://cdn.microthosting.com/imgs/Screenshot_at_2017-06-15_12-02-58.png

http://cdn.microthosting.com/imgs/Screenshot_at_2017-06-15_12-03-13.png

Comment: This means your class is not set up properly. There are a few things that need to be true before you can inject the `Http` class into your class. Check this tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: This article has more details about the `HttpModule`: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-new-http-module-1278499db2a0